# Plus and min Array by show undefined

Tags: jquery

```
var letterbox = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I",];

var counter = -1;

  $(".plusbtn").click(function(){
    counter = (counter + 1) % letterbox.length;
    $(".ux--wrapper").empty();
    $(".ux--wrapper").append("<p>"+letterbox[counter]+"</p>");
  });

  $(".minbtn").click(function(){
    counter = (counter - 1) % letterbox.length;
    $(".ux--wrapper").empty();
    $(".ux--wrapper").append("<p>"+letterbox[counter]+"</p>");
  });
```

my intention is when i click **+** it increase the array by 1 and same on **-** decrease array by 1 , but somehow the **-** when you are below "A" it show undefined, how do i make it jump to the last of my array (which is I") when is Below "A" ?? or is there a better way for doing this, please show your advice.

[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/Tedeee/r9cc2c4r/)
try click **-** when start.

Comment: Runnable HTML/CSS/JavaScript demos should be posted *on-site*, using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button), rather than off-site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider when `counter` is `0`. This line:

```
counter = (counter - 1) % letterbox.length;
```

...sets `counter` to `-1`. The wrap-around trick doesn't work going backward like that. `letterbox[-1]` is `undefined`, because `letterbox` doesn't have a property with the name `"-1"`.

The wrap-around trick does work if you do this:

```
counter = (counter + letterbox.length - 1) % letterbox.length;
```